Why does Elecard add +12 to the QP (Quantization Parameter) when analyzing VTM-encoded bitstreams?
I have encoded a video using the VTM encoder. However, when I use Elecard StreamEye 2023 to analyze the bitstream, I notice that it adds +12 to the QP (Quantization Parameter).
I'm trying to understand the rationale behind this adjustment.
I encoded a video using the VTM encoder and analyzed the bitstream with Elecard StreamEye 2023. I expected the QP values to match those set during the VTM encoding process. However, I noticed that Elecard StreamEye 2023 consistently adds +12 to the QP values.
When I decode the bitstream with VTM and display the logs, the QP values match those I set during encoding. However, when using Elecard StreamEye 2023, the QP values are always +12 higher than expected.
I would appreciate any insights or explanations on why Elecard StreamEye 2023 applies this +12 adjustment to the QP when analyzing VTM-encoded bitstreams.
